# Strange access permission behaviour

Tags: permissions, syslog

I have 4 Ubuntu boxes.
In one of them `Tower1` I have to use `sudo` to `grep /var/log/syslog`

```
$ grep CRON /var/log/syslog | grep daily
grep: /var/log/syslog: Permission denied
$ sudo grep CRON /var/log/syslog | grep daily
Mar 10 06:25:01 Tower1 CRON[3649067]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
Mar 11 06:25:01 Tower1 CRON[2002487]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
Mar 12 06:25:01 Tower1 CRON[355962]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
Mar 13 06:25:01 Tower1 CRON[3095340]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
$ ll /var/log/syslog
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 2,6G mar 14 02:45 /var/log/syslog
```

but in the other 3 (e.g., `Tower2`) I don't need sudo

```
$ grep CRON /var/log/syslog | grep daily
Mar 10 06:25:01 Tower2 CRON[119866]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
Mar 11 06:25:01 Tower2 CRON[124499]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
Mar 12 06:25:01 Tower2 CRON[135499]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
Mar 13 06:25:01 Tower2 CRON[160398]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
$ ll /var/log/syslog
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 1594833 Mar 14 02:57 /var/log/syslog
```

In all 4 cases I was logged in via ssh as a sudoer user, but not as root.

What could cause the difference?
Having RDP sessions opened? (I guess that has nothing to do)

Comment: Is the logged in user a member of the `adm` group in all cases?

Comment: why is this strange and not normal behavious? see the user and group permissions: those are different for these log files.

Comment: @rinzwind how are they different? They both have ownership as `syslog:adm`, and permissions are `640`.

Comment: @steeldriver - Silly me! It turns out that in `Tower1`, due to some issues I had to recreate some time ago the user `user1`. So it was now member only of `user1 sudo`.
In the other 3 boxes, `user1` was a member of `user1 adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare`, as installers of the OS.
Even if silly, I would post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it and close the OP.